# How to move a https certificate from a shared hosting to a vps?

Tags: iis, https, directadmin

I have a shared hosting I can manage via DirectAdmin.I have configured a https certificate on it.Now I want to move my website to a vps that uses IIS6.0.But I don't know how to install the https certificate on my vps?
Could I export it from my shared hosting?Or do I have to reapply a https certificate?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have known the answer to my question.
I generate *.pfx via command "openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt" on ubuntu.I copy server.key and server.crt from SSL panel of DirectAdmin.They are string,not file.
And then,I import the *.pfx into IIS6.Now it works.
That's all.Thank you.